# Getting a JavaScript issue due to a 500 server error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

In open cart I have a custom module - with ajax filter - when trying to use the filter i'm getting following errors.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#btnForm").fancybox({
width: 1000,
height: 1050,
autoSize : false,
fitToView : false,
closeBtn : false,
maxWidth : '100%'
});
$(function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: <?php echo $max_price ?>,
        values: [ <?php echo $start_price ?>, <?php echo $end_price ?> ],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( "<?php echo $curr ?>" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - <?php echo $curr ?  >" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
        $("#results").html('<img src="catalog/view/theme/pollishop2/image/ajax-loader.gif" />');
        $("#pagination").html('');
        clearTimeout(wto);
        wto = setTimeout(function() {
        filter();
        }, 100);
        }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( "<?php echo $curr ?>" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) + " - <?php echo $curr ?>" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
});
var wto;
$(".checkish").change(function() {
$("#results").html('<img src="catalog/view/theme/pollishop2/image/ajax-loader.gif" />');
$("#pagination").html('');
clearTimeout(wto);
wto = setTimeout(function() {
filter();
}, 100);
});
$("input[type='text']").change(function() {
$("#results").html('<img src="catalog/view/theme/pollishop2/image/ajax-loader.gif" />');
$("#pagination").html('');
filter();
});
function mrvidaloca(filter, page) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=information/jewels/xml' + filter,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {       
            all_jewels = json.all_jewels;
            pagination = json.pagination;
            doolittle = '';
                $.each( all_jewels, function( key, value ) {
                    doolittle += '<div style="text-align:left;padding-bottom:10px;margin- right:1px;">';
                        doolittle += '<div class="image"><a href="' + value.view + '"><img  src="' + value.image + '" /></a></div>';
                    doolittle += '<div class="name"><a style="font-size:16px;" href="' +  value.view + '">' + value.title + '</a></div>';
                        doolittle += '<div class="description" style="display:block;">' +  value.description + '</div>';
                       doolittle += '<div class="rating"  style="right:10px;position:absolute;z-index:3;top:0;"><img  src="catalog/view/theme/pollishop2/image/stars-' + value.rating + '.png" /></div>';
                    doolittle += '</div>';
                });
        if(doolittle){
        $("#results").html(doolittle);
        $("#pagination").html(pagination);
        } else {
        $("#results").html('<?php echo $no_results ?>');
        $("#pagination").html('');
        }

        }
    });
}
function filter(page) {
url = '';
var filter_named = $('#mans').find('input[name="searchjewellery"]').val();
if (filter_named) {
url += '&term=' + filter_named;
}
var filter_name = $('input[name=\'price\']').attr('value');
if (filter_name) {
filter_name = filter_name.replace(/<?php echo $curr ?>/g, '');
filter_name = filter_name.split(' ').join('');
filter_name = filter_name.split('-');
url += '&start_price=' + filter_name[0] + '&end_price=' + filter_name[1];
}
var filter_cat = $('input[name=\'cat\']').attr('value');
if (filter_cat) {
url += '&jewels_category_id=' + filter_cat;
}
var vali = [];
   $('#god :checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
   vali[i] = $(this).val();
   });
lashes = vali.join(',');
if(lashes) {
url += '&difficulty=' + lashes;
}
var valio = [];
   $('#bios :checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
   valio[i] = $(this).val();
   });
helium = valio.join(',');
if(helium) {
url += '&designer_id=' + helium;
}
if(page){
url += '&page=' + page;
} else {
url += '&page=1';
}

mrvidaloca(url,page);
}
</script>
```

**Console shows:**

```
GET http://test.risetea.co.uk/index.php?route=information/jewels/xml&start_price=$0&end_price=$500&jewels_category_id=5&difficulty=1&pa ge=1 500 (Internal Server Error)
jquery-1.8.3.min.js?j2v=2.3.3:2 v.support.ajax.v.ajaxTransport.send
jquery-1.8.3.min.js?j2v=2.3.3:2 v.extend.ajax
index.php?route=information/jewels&jewels_category_id=5:989 mrvidaloca
```

index.php?route=information/jewels&jewels_category_id=5:1054 filter
   index.php?route=information/jewels&jewels_category_id=5:980 (anonymous function)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not Javascript error. It is `500 (Internal Server Error)` which means that you have problems on your server side.

Comment: Right - Sorted Store was set to USD and the module was looking for £s - changed the currency now no errors. Thanks again.